# pymongo - how to match on lookup?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have two collections, a model and a papers collection. I need to be able to match fields from both of them. They have a field in common called reference which contains an identifier.

I want to match documents that have the following

'authors' : 'Migliore M' from the papers collection
'celltypes' : 'Hippocampus CA3 pyramidal cell' from the models collection

Here is what my code looks like:

```
pipeline = [{'$lookup': 
                {'from' : 'models',
                 'localField' : 'references',
                 'foreignField' : 'references',
                 'as' : 'cellmodels'}},
             {'$match':
                 {'authors' : 'Migliore M', 'cellmodels.celltypes' : 'Hippocampus CA3 pyramidal cell'}},


             ]

for doc in (papers.aggregate(pipeline)):
    pprint (doc)
```

I get no results.

I notice that if I do not call on the cellmodels.celltypes in the match parameter it will find the papers that match Migliore M. How can I get it to also match the celltype:'Hippocampus CA3 pyramidal cell' from the models collection in this query?

Comment: You just need to `{'$unwind': '$cellmodels'}` before `$match`.

Comment: Not exactly sure the unwind did anything, but I was able to get it to work

Comment: The lookup returns array so unwind will convert arrays into objects and you can apply comparison to embedded fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked:

```
pipeline = [{'$lookup': 
                {'from' : 'models',
                 'localField' : '_id',
                 'foreignField' : 'references',
                 'as' : 'cellmodels'}},
            {'$unwind': '$cellmodels'},
             {'$match':
                 {'authors' : 'Migliore M', 'cellmodels.celltypes' : 'Hippocampus CA3 pyramidal cell'}},
            {'$project': 
                {'authors':1, 'cellmodels.celltypes':1}} 
             ]

for doc in (papers.aggregate(pipeline)):
    pprint (doc)
```