# How to copy values from one mongo document into a nested field in another in python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have two collections in the mongo database. At the moment I have an ID document from collection1 in document in collection2. I want to copy some values from Collection1 to nested field (dataFromCollection1) in related documents in Collection2. I'm looking for help because I can not find a solution to pass values from the mongo base fields to variables in python.

```
 Collection1:
    { 
        "_id" : ObjectId("583d498214f89c3f08b10e2d"), 
        "name" : "Name", 
        "gender" : "men", 
        "secondName" : "", 
        "testData" : [    ], 
        "numberOf" : NumberInt(0), 
        "place" : "", 
        "surname" : "Surname", 
        "field1" : "eggs", 
        "field2" : "hamm", 
        "field3" : "foo", 
        "field4" : "bar" 
    }


Collection2:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b028e26900ed21d5153a36"), 
    "collection1" : ObjectId("583d498214f89c3f08b10e2d")
    "fieldCol2_1" : "123", 
    "fieldCol2_2" : "332", 
    "fieldCol2_3" : "133",
    "dataFromCollection1" : {
        "name" : " ", 
        "surname" : " ", 
        "field1" : " ", 
        "field2" : " ", 
        "field3" : " ", 
        "field4" : " "
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read from first collection and use update operation in second collection to save the data in second collection. Please remember to use $set property in the update operation.Otherwise the existing data will lost.

Comment: Which python library currently you are using to connect with MongoDB?

Comment: @LakmalVithanage I need only 5-6 field from 20 field in Collection1. Can i choose which fields will be added to collection2? Can you send some examples?

Comment: @jarryjafery  I use pymongo.

Comment: @KrzysztofKozłowski, Yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use aggregate function in pymongo package, in aggregate you can use $lookup to match the key value pairs and project for projecting the required fields this question has already been asked so this [pymongo - how to match on lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992885/pymongo-how-to-match-on-lookup) might helps you.
Then you can use the $out function in aggregate to create the new updated collection of your interest or you can also update the existing collection by using the update in pymongo.